# What signals can I send to gracefully shutdown netty server?

Tags: signals, netty, shutdown

As we all known, when we write a Netty Server, we usually call `bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();` in the finally region. And I look the `shutdownGracefully()` comment, it says:

> Signals this executor that the caller wants the executor to be shut down.

```
    public final class EchoServer {

    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8007"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EchoServerHandler echoServerHandler = new EchoServerHandler();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                            p.addLast(echoServerHandler);
                        }
                    });

            ChannelFuture f = serverBootstrap.bind(PORT).sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            // todo, how to here
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, the server will never come to `bossGroup.shutdownGraceFully()` line, because `f.channel().closeFuture().sync();` will block the main thread.

So my question is:

1. how can it come to `bossGroup.shutdownGracefully()` line?
2. or what signal can I send to gracefully shutdown a netty server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you want to shut your server down?? And why?

Why not build a handler for the server, which you can pass your `EchoServer` class to - then, you can configure a message to hit a `stop` method in your `EchoServer`.

The `stop` method can then hit the `shutdownGracefully` etc.

You'll just need to arrange your code so these parts are broken down into methods you hit, start/stop for example.

In my implementation, the only time a `stop` method is called is when the code explicitly calls it.